# ASP.NET MVC redirect to action Redirect Loops

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning asp.net MVC and I was trying Redirect to action and I tried the following code and I keep getting Redirect Loop Error.
This is  the Controller class in which I am getting an error

```
  public class CuisineController : Controller
{
    // GET: Cuisine
    public ActionResult Search(string name)
    {


        return RedirectToAction("About","Cuisine");

    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("This is Index");
    }
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return Content("this is About");
    }
}
```

I have also created a route of my own other than the Default route

```
 routes.MapRoute(name: "Cuisine",
            url: "cuisine/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Cuisine", action = "Search", name = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

When I try to access the Cuisine controller it gives me a redirect loop error.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routeConfig, you have a route defined for "`cuisine/{name}`" and it will be sent to the Search action method.

In your `Search` action method, You are redirecting to the `About`, Which is `cuisine/About`. This is matching with the route you defined `cuisine/{name}` so it will send the request to Search action again.   The same process will keep running. That is why you are getting the redirect loop

You should either delete this specific route you defined or rename the url pattern for cusine search to prevent the redirect loop.

```
 routes.MapRoute(name: "Cuisine",
            url: "searchcuisine/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Cuisine", action = "Search", 
                                                          name = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be pretty obvious:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Cuisine",
url: "cuisine/{name}",
defaults: new { controller = "Cuisine", action = "Search", name = UrlParameter.Optional })
```

Says **all** urls that start with `cuisine/` use the `Search` method on the `CuisineController`.

`/Cuisine/About` starts with that url, so it willl **always** use the `Search` method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to make {name} part of URL. You can use attribute routing instead of changing default routing, it does not have such global "destructive" effects (explained in other answers) at least, and looks it's what you are actually after :)

```
[Route("Search/{name}")]
public ActionResult Search(string name)
{
    return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
}
```

See more about attribute routing [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) (for this to work, don't forget to add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` if it is not there yet).

Answer (score 0):

You need to restore controller action pattern. Just change `url: "cuisine/{name}"` to `url: "cuisine/{action}/{name}"`